# Why does strict complain about variables from a required other script?

Tags: perl, require, perl-module, strict

This is usex.pl:

```
#use strict;
require 'x.pl';
print $x;
```

Here is x.pl:

```
#use strict;
our $x = 99;
1;
```

It runs fine as shown.  If I uncomment the line to use strict in usesx.pl, I get

```
Global symbol "$x" requires explicit package name
```

The use or not of strict in x.pl seems not to matter (unless I drop the 'our' keyword, but I'm not interested in that.)

I'm fairly new to Perl.   Why does strict make $x not visible in the main script, and what is the normal solution to this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hehe, `our` is not easy to grok as it mixes the concepts of global and lexical scope. What it does is exempting a global variable from the `strict 'vars'` pragma and allowing unqualified access to it within its scope, which is the enclosing block, or the end of the current file, whatever comes first. [Read the full (but brief) story in the manual](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/our.html), which is also accessible by saying `perldoc -f our` on the command line.

As for your script, you can verify the truthfulness of the words in the manual by modifying the variable accessor to use a package-qualified name:

```
use strict;
require 'x.pl';
print $main::x;
```

Answer (score 7):

Two reasons.

1. The error happens at compile-time, before `require` is ever executed. That's easy to fix using `BEGIN`.
2. `our` is lexically-scoped, and it's in a different lexical scope (file or block) than the `print`, so it's no longer in effect.

The whole approach is fundamentally bad. Here's one better way:

```
package MyConfig;
use strict;
use warnings;
use Exporter qw( import );
our @EXPORT = qw( $x );
our $x = 123;
1;

use strict;
use warnings;
use MyConfig;
print "$x\n";
```